# Unique grouped constraint on SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

In T-SQL I am after a constraint that will stop duplicate records being inserted for the  flag.

For each [FK_Something] the flag `[MyFlag]` can only be set once to value 1 but can be set to 0 many times.

Is this possible and is so how without using triggers?

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
set nocount on

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MyTable]') AND type in (N'U'))
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [id]            [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FK_Something]  [int] NOT NULL,
    [MyFlag]        [bit] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--  Valid inserts   --
INSERT INTO [MyTable]   ([FK_Something],[MyFlag])    VALUES  (1,0);
INSERT INTO [MyTable]   ([FK_Something],[MyFlag])    VALUES  (1,1);
INSERT INTO [MyTable]   ([FK_Something],[MyFlag])    VALUES  (1,0);
INSERT INTO [MyTable]   ([FK_Something],[MyFlag])    VALUES  (2,0);
INSERT INTO [MyTable]   ([FK_Something],[MyFlag])    VALUES  (2,0);
INSERT INTO [MyTable]   ([FK_Something],[MyFlag])    VALUES  (2,0);
INSERT INTO [MyTable]   ([FK_Something],[MyFlag])    VALUES  (2,1);

---------------------------------------
-- Inserts Should Fail  
-- As [MyFlag] set for [FK_Something]
---------------------------------------
INSERT INTO [MyTable]   ([FK_Something],[MyFlag])    VALUES  (1,1)   
GO

INSERT INTO [MyTable]   ([FK_Something],[MyFlag])    VALUES  (2,1)
GO

-- Constraint should apply this logic --
Declare @FK_Something   INT
Declare @MyFlag         INT
set @FK_Something = 2
Set @MyFlag       = 0

if( @myflag = 0 OR
    not exists(Select 1 from [MyTable] where FK_Something = @FK_Something and MyFlag = @MyFlag))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [MyTable]   ([FK_Something],[MyFlag])  VALUES  (@FK_Something,@MyFlag);
    print 'Inserted ';
END
GO

select * from [MyTable]
```

Comment: Create a filtered unique index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mack for his suggestion of using a function.  I had to change the function logic in the function as it did not allow for the first record to be inserted.  I have posted the complete solution for neatness below.  TomTom's solution of the index does not involve a function so a lot of companies would accept it more.  Both are in the code below, have a play and choose the right solution for your needs.

```
set nocount on
ALTER TABLE myTable drop CONSTRAINT chkFkPk 
go
drop  FUNCTION dbo.CheckMyTableFlag;
go
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MyTable]') AND type in (N'U'))
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [id]            [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FK_Something]  [int] NOT NULL,
    [MyFlag]        [bit] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/*
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckMyTableFlag(@FK_Something INT)
    RETURNS INT
AS 
BEGIN

    Declare @retVal     INT = 0
    Select @retVal = sum(cast([myflag] as int)) from MyTable WHERE FK_Something = @FK_Something group by FK_Something

    RETURN @retVal
END;
GO


ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT chkFkPk CHECK (dbo.CheckMyTableFlag(FK_Something) <2 );
*/
go
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Whatever
    ON MyTable (FK_Something, myFlag)
    WHERE MyFlag = 1

go
----  Valid inserts   --
INSERT INTO [MyTable]   ([FK_Something],[MyFlag])    VALUES  (1,0); 
INSERT INTO [MyTable]   ([FK_Something],[MyFlag])    VALUES  (1,0);  
INSERT INTO [MyTable]   ([FK_Something],[MyFlag])    VALUES  (1,1);
INSERT INTO [MyTable]   ([FK_Something],[MyFlag])    VALUES  (1,0);
INSERT INTO [MyTable]   ([FK_Something],[MyFlag])    VALUES  (2,0);
INSERT INTO [MyTable]   ([FK_Something],[MyFlag])    VALUES  (2,0);
INSERT INTO [MyTable]   ([FK_Something],[MyFlag])    VALUES  (2,0);
INSERT INTO [MyTable]   ([FK_Something],[MyFlag])    VALUES  (2,1);

-----------------------------------------
---- Inserts Should Fail  
---- As [MyFlag] set for [FK_Something]
-----------------------------------------
INSERT INTO [MyTable]   ([FK_Something],[MyFlag])    VALUES  (1,1)   
GO

INSERT INTO [MyTable]   ([FK_Something],[MyFlag])    VALUES  (2,1)
GO

select [id],[FK_Something],[MyFlag]  from mytable
go
```

Answer (score 2):

Indices.

> For each [FK_Something] the flag [MyFlag] can only be set once to
>   value 1 but can be set to 0 many times.

That is 1 simle index:

- FK_Something and MyFlag 1 - unique

The trick here is to not apply the unique index on ALL rows, which is why you add a filter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx

explains the syntax which would look like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Whatever
    ON MyTable (FK_Something, myFlag)
    WHERE MyFlag = 1
```

Simpler than a constraint and guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a user defined function within a check constraint:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ChkFn(
    @FK_Something INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MyFlag         INT
    SET @MyFlag       = 0

    IF( @myflag = 0 OR
        NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 
                    FROM [MyTable]
                    WHERE FK_Something = @FK_Something 
                    AND MyFlag = @MyFlag))
    BEGIN
        SET @retval=1;
    END

    RETURN @retval
END;
GO

ALTER TABLE myTable
ADD CONSTRAINT chkFkPk CHECK (dbo.ChekFn(FK_Something) = 1 );
GO
```

Try it and let me know if it worked. 
I haven't tested this.

Be aware that this might fail for multirow updates or under snapshot isolation.